# Visual Studio 2012 c# ListView issue - kinda strange one

Tags: c#, listview, visual-studio-2012

I'll try to explain best I can.

I have a ListView in visual studio c# form, with a function to populate it. When I recently tried to update that ListView by adding a column, it just showed only previous columns populated. Then, for an even greater surprise. When I changed function text in order to populate "old" columns a bit differently just to make sure it works (like, adding string "test string" to a column populating string) nothing happened - it just stayed the old way. After that, I completely erased population function body, leaving nothing inside brackets - and listview was still populated with data, like it called the original version of function, even though I had just erased it completely. Left me puzzled. Failed to google anything similar. More funny stuff - i put a MessageBox into function body just to make sure that "new" function is called at all. And yes, MessageBox is being displayed so it actually accepts that change of function. Code to show it:

```
private void populateMissionList() 
           {
        this.listView1.Items.Clear();
        List<MisijaDTO> misije = MisijaDAO.ocitajSve();

        foreach (MisijaDTO mission in misije) 
        {


            string idmisije = "" + mission.Id;
            ListViewItem stavka = new ListViewItem(idmisije);
            stavka.SubItems.Add(mission.Naziv);  // "old" column
            stavka.SubItems.Add(mission.Datum + " test string"); //"old" column, but won't show newly added "test string"
            if (mission.Uspjesna){
                stavka.SubItems.Add("Uspješna"); // "new" column, won't be shown... 
             MessageBox.Show("282 true"); //... but this text box is shown
            }
            else {stavka.SubItems.Add("Neuspješna");MessageBox.Show("282 false");}
            listView1.Items.Add(stavka);

        }
    }
```

My best guess why this happened - I have previously cut that listView from the form, pasted it onto another form (which I used as a backup), and later copied it from backup form and pasted it back onto original form. I suppose ListView somehow got stuck with the old function definition, but I wasn't able to solve it. Tried to: rename ListView, rename population function, clean solution, rebuild solution, close and reopen Visual Studio... nothing helped. It's not database problem either, because it will read new database imports into ListView, but limited to "old" set of columns like it won't recognize ListView that I pasted back. ListView name remaine same after cut/paste/copy/paste, so I guess that's not issue either.

If you need some more information, I'd be glad to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the .designer.cs file where the Column Collection is populated. You probably need to add another column into that....

Comment: Column collection is populated properly in .designer.cs. I don't think that's the problem actually, because even "old" columns won't accept any data change - like it's calling a ghost part of function to populate columns.

Answer (score 0):

I owe A BIG apologie to anyone who spent their precious time reading this topic. There isn't any bug or something, but I overlooked some piece of code that was related to my function and that populated list the old way separately. Seems everything works just fine right now.

Good side of this is that I signed up for Stack Overflow finally :)